# What is "UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop" in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, translate

I want to make a custom transition segue in Xcode but I can't program in any language, so I searched an instruction. My problem is now, that this instruction is written in Objektive C unlike my App which is written in Swift so I got to "translate"! Swift doesn't know that "UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop" (this is Objective C). Does anyone know, how to put this line in swift?

Answer (score 3):

Enums in swift don't repeat the prefix, so it's `.TransitionFlipFromTop`. If you just look up the documentation for the Objective-C enum, it gives the Swift counterpart.

Go here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions

And tap the link in the upper-right that shows Swift (or both)

Answer (score 1):

This one may help you.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.25, delay: 0.0, options: [.TransitionFlipFromTop], animations: {

        /* You can also add more UIViewAnimationOptions to the array */

        }, completion: {(bool: Bool) -> Void in

    })
```